Way to Implement Color Pallet in Bar Chart in Workshop Module
I want to apply the color pallet in the Bar chart. currently, I'm starting with the 3 basic colors and I want to repeat that in the Bar chart series.
I'm not able to find any way to do that using the Workshop UI.
I also tried it with segments, but that's not how I want Bar to be plotted, so if there is any way to implement that using the Code repository or UI, please let me suggest!
Below is the reference picture of how I want to plot a Bar chart.

